# RPN calculator error message addition

Tags: java, calculator, rpn

I have been working on this calculator for a class assignment and cannot seam to figure out where to place an "error" statement if there are not enough numbers for the amount of processors. 
I am allowed to have extra numbers (i.e. 3 3 3 +), but not too few (i.e. 3 +)

Please let me know if there are any ideas you have...

```
 import java.util.*;
 class RPNCalculator{

 public static void main (String [] str){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter numbers and operations in PRN format");
  String input = scan.nextLine();
  String [] split = input.split("\\s+");
  double [] numbers = new double [1000];
  int numAmount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
      if (split[i].equals("+")){
        numbers[numAmount-2] = numbers[numAmount-2] + numbers[numAmount-1];
        numAmount--;
      }
      else if (split[i].equals("-")){
        numbers[numAmount-2] = numbers[numAmount-2] - numbers[numAmount-1];
        numAmount--;
      }
      else if (split[i].equals("*")){
        numbers[numAmount-2] = numbers[numAmount-2] * numbers[numAmount-1];
        numAmount--;
      }
      else if (split[i].equals("/")){
        numbers[numAmount-2] = numbers[numAmount-2] / numbers[numAmount-1];
        numAmount--;
      } 
      else {
        numbers[numAmount] = Double.parseDouble(split[i]);
        numAmount++; 
      }
    }
  System.out.print (numbers[numAmount-1]);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Your approach looks completely wrong to me.  A reverse Polish notation calculator should be using a _stack_ data structure, onto which you will push the operands.  Google "RPN stack Java".

Comment: If it's already in post-fix the hard part's done. You can use the reliable - pop, pop, evaluate, push. Although, I don't know why anyone would allow "extra numbers" as it seems invalid.